# Get the content by page id/slug with the Wordpress Rest API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

Using the Wordpress Rest API as my backend and Nuxt.js as my Front-end but trying to get the data from pages by ID/Slug as the pages will be filled with the Gutenberg blocks... Now I have the problem I only get the first ID and have done the map structure with

1. Onderwijs/
2. index.vue
3. _slug.vue

```
export default {
  async asyncData ({ app, store, params }) {
    let page = await app.$axios.get(`${store.state.wordpressAPI}/wp/v2/pages?parent=77&_embed`)
    store.commit('setPage', page.data[0])
  },

  computed: {
    page () {
        return this.$store.state.page
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could you show your HTML part, where you render your stuff?
Something like:

```
<div :id="page.title.rendered" exact class="page__content" v-html="page.content.rendered"></div>
```